# Who bundles react-native code?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

When we create ***React app*,** we need to convert ***jsx*** into ***js*** and ***babel*** does this.

We may use gulp or webpack as well for building final code that can be executed by the browsers.

With **React-Native**, we are still using ***jsx*** and ***.babelrc*** file containing ***"react-native"*** as only required preset. It is clear that babel is converting jsx to native code.

My query is "Which bundler is being used by **ReactNative**?". How babel takes jsx to convert it to native code? Is ***ReactNative*** using gulp, grunt, webpack or something else?

- If yes, how to customize this configuration? Which file is
  available for this purpose? (Say i want to use traceur instead of babel)
- If no, can we use gulp or webpack with
  react-native without creating project using **react-native init** command?

Answer (score 2):

React Native uses its own packager (included in the React Native's code: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/packager).

Under the hood it uses Babel, that's why you see a `.babelrc` in the project's root.

The main reason they didn't use something more standard like webpack is because it didn't seem to be fast enough for React Native's projects so Facebook decided to create their own packager. If you want to know more about it, you can check this issue in github: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5 where they discuss about how to overcome the packaging issues they faced when using webpack. It's one of the first issues and really fun to read if you are into React Native's internals

Comment: You missed to answer the question "If yes, how to customize this configuration? Which file is available for this purpose? (Say i want to use traceur instead of babel)" which i am interested to know.